# Tamaño de columna fijo en una tabla Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

¿Como logro que el tamaño de la columna sea el mismo para todas?

He intentado cambiando el atributo `width` a un valor fijo o utilizando `col-md-*` dentro de los `<th>` pero no cambia nada, el tamaño de la columna se esta ajustando automaticamente al contenido.

Yo quiero que sea vea uniforme, que todas las columnas tengan el mismo tamaño, por ejemplo `130px`. Y que si deseo ver el resto del contenido utilizo el scroll horizontal.

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table users table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>I.E.</th>
                <th>Topografia</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Esquema Básico Arquitectonico</th> 
                <th></th>
                <th>Anteproyecto Arquitectonico</th> 
                <th></th>
                <th>Proyecto Arquitectonico</th>
                <th></th>                                                                       
                <th>Estudio Geotecnico</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Diseño Estructural</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Diseño Hidrosanitario</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Diseño Electrico</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>                  
            </thead>
          </table>  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo que puedes realizar es utilizar la propiedad `table-layout: fixed` en tu tabla de bootstrap.

Posteriormente, y como `Bootstrap` tiene una **[especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad)** más grande para sus elementos, tendremos que utilizar un selector con una especificidad mayor. Yo en este caso le he asignado un id a la fila que contiene todos los `th` y he tomado como referencia este `id` para poder dar las propiedades a las diferentes `th` que se encuentran en la tabla.

```
#miTablaPersonalizada th{
  width: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

La propiedad `overflow: auto` la utilizo para que, en caso de ser necesario el scroll, este aparezca automáticamente. También podrías usar `overflow-x` para hacer referencia solamente al scroll horizontal o `overflow-y` para hacer referencia al scroll vertical.

Este es tu ejemplo modificado. Le he puesto un borde a cada una de las cabeceras de columnas (`th`) para que se pueda ver que todas tienen el mismo tamaño.

```css
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#miTablaPersonalizada th{
  width: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table users table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr id="miTablaPersonalizada">
                <th>I.E.</th>
                <th>Topografia</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Esquema Básico Arquitectonico</th> 
                <th></th>
                <th>Anteproyecto Arquitectonico</th> 
                <th></th>
                <th>Proyecto Arquitectonico</th>
                <th></th>                                                                       
                <th>Estudio Geotecnico</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Diseño Estructural</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Diseño Hidrosanitario</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Diseño Electrico</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>                  
            </thead>
          </table>  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Me he topado con este tipo de escenarios y la forma como lo he resuelto es agregando un `div` dentro del `th` o `td` con una `clase` y poniendole el `width` a la calse:

HTML

```
<th><div class="size"> I.E.</div></th>
```

CSS

```
.size{
  width: 330px;
}
```

Mira el ejemplo, espero poder ayudarte... saludos :-)

```css
.size{
  width: 330px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table users table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><div class="size"> I.E.</div></th>
                <th><div class="size">Topografia</div></th>
                <th><div class="size">Esquema Básico Arquitectonico</div></th>
                <th><div class="size">Anteproyecto Arquitectonico</div></th>
                <th><div class="size">Proyecto Arquitectonico</div></th>
                <th><div class="size">Estudio Geotecnico</div></th>
                <th><div class="size">Diseño Estructural</div></th>
                <th><div class="size">Diseño Hidrosanitario</div></th>
                <th><div class="size">Diseño Electrico</div></th>
              </tr>                  
            </thead>
          </table>  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución es de crear un estilo css,

### Ejemplo:

```
.ancho-columna{
    width: 19%;
}
```

El **ancho** tiene que estar en **porcentaje**.